# unity array having 50 gameobjects but displays only 10 object

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, menu, multi-level, levels

i have build a level menu with levels, i also created and empty array (GameObject[ ] lvlBut; )to store the level icons instantiated, but only 10 level icons are displayed on the screen where as i have 50 levels. for some reason its only taking 10 levels and i don’t t know where i have gone wrong. any suggestions?

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class LevelSelector : MonoBehaviour{


    public GameObject levelHolder;
    public GameObject levelIcon;
    public GameObject thisCanvas;
    public int numberOfLevels = 50;
    public Vector2 iconSpacing;
    private Rect panelDimensions;
    private Rect iconDimensions;
    private int amountPerPage;
    private int currentLevelCount;

    int levelsUnlocked;
    GameObject[] lvlBut;
    
    void Start()
    {
        panelDimensions = levelHolder.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
        iconDimensions = levelIcon.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
        int maxInARow = Mathf.FloorToInt((panelDimensions.width + iconSpacing.x) / (iconDimensions.width + iconSpacing.x));
        int maxInACol = Mathf.FloorToInt((panelDimensions.height + iconSpacing.y) / (iconDimensions.height + iconSpacing.y));
        amountPerPage = maxInARow * maxInACol;
        int totalPages = Mathf.CeilToInt((float)numberOfLevels / amountPerPage);
        LoadPanels(totalPages);
  
    }
    void LoadPanels(int numberOfPanels)
    {
        GameObject panelClone = Instantiate(levelHolder) as GameObject;
        PageSwiper swiper = levelHolder.AddComponent<PageSwiper>();
        swiper.totalPages = numberOfPanels;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPanels; i++)
        {
            GameObject panel = Instantiate(panelClone) as GameObject;
            panel.transform.SetParent(thisCanvas.transform, false);
            panel.transform.SetParent(levelHolder.transform);
            panel.name = "Page-" + i;
            panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector2(panelDimensions.width * (i - 1), 0);
            SetUpGrid(panel);
            int numberOfIcons = i == numberOfPanels ? numberOfLevels - currentLevelCount : amountPerPage;
            LoadIcons(numberOfIcons, panel);
        }
        Destroy(panelClone);
    }
    void SetUpGrid(GameObject panel)
    {
        GridLayoutGroup grid = panel.AddComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        grid.cellSize = new Vector2(iconDimensions.width, iconDimensions.height);
        grid.childAlignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        grid.spacing = iconSpacing;
    }
    void LoadIcons(int numberOfIcons, GameObject parentObject)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfIcons; i++)
        {
            currentLevelCount++;
            GameObject icon = Instantiate(levelIcon) as GameObject;
            icon.transform.SetParent(thisCanvas.transform, false);
            icon.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
            icon.name = "Level " + i;
            icon.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().SetText(currentLevelCount.ToString());
        } 
        lvlBut = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("LevelButton");
        levelsUnlocked = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked", 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < lvlBut.Length; i++)
        {
            lvlBut[i].GetComponentInChildren<Button>().interactable = false;

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < levelsUnlocked; i++)
        {
            lvlBut[i].GetComponentInChildren<Button>().interactable = true;

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Without going through your code .. Are you sure you didn't change the number in the Inspector? And are you sure there is only 10 things spawned it are they maybe overlapping?

Comment: Also I don't quite understand your logic behind instantiating the panel clone in order to later destroy it and why are you always using `SetParent` twice? A bit confusing .. you know you can just assign the position and rotation without changing the hierarchy?

Comment: @derHugo , yes even in the inspector its 50, yes when i play the game i see only 1 page and 10 levels. the reason to set parent twice is cuz when set it to just 'levelHolder' it does not maintain the same size so, i 1st set the parent to canvas and then to 'levelHolder'.

Comment: Did you try to instantiate the gameobjects without grid? Make this happen first then move to next method.

Comment: @derHugo, and the reason for me to delete the panel clone is, i use it as a model to create future pages, and once done i destroy it.

Comment: @Yugerten without the grid the icons lap each other and only 10 icons are displayed. with or without the grid it takes in only 10 icons.

Comment: @DeepakBohra I know, just to make sure that there is no problem with Loading Icons to the scene, and this is the important part.

Comment: @Yugerten , yes i just tried what u suggested, but with or without the grid it takes in only 10 icons.

Comment: How many pages is it telling you? Are you sure its mot just showing page 1 of 5?

Comment: @BugFinder its showing only 1 page and only 10 leavels.

Comment: hi guys, i found a fix, all the 50 levels are displayed with 5 pages, to fix the issue, i simply moved the array in the start method, after `LoadPanel()`.  now my start method looks like this. but now am not able to lock the levels, all the levels are unlocked.

Comment: hi guys i figured it out. everything is working fine. thanks a lot for your time and effort.